# Setting Process States

Tags: operating-system

i was studying how the operating system switches between process to optimize the throughput of the CPU so whenever the code requests a I/O call the operating systems Scheduler sets the process state as Blocked as long as the process waits for the I/O request to be completed, My question is as the OS is responsible for marking the process as blocked and after doing so another process starts executing and the OS goes to sleep until the next interrupt, where it then Schedules between the Ready Processes, once the I/O is done unless how does the OS mark the process as Ready and how does it even know that the I/O is done? is there some sort of an interrupt that causes the OS to wake up again and set the Process State to Ready From Blocked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is very general, and there are surely a lot of different answers. One answer is: If a device that was directed to do some operation, say write to a hard disk, finishes its operation, it may simply pull down electrically an interrupt line on the device bus, which notifies the CPU of this event. The CPU then starts an exception processing, during which it reads the device response and clears the interrupt. This may also set the responsible process to ready.

Comment: This is entirely system dependent and may vary among device types.